# Winamp freeze at exit

Tags: freeze, crash, winamp

Im on an XP SP3 machine and the newest Winamp v5.63 has a small problem.
It hangs on exit.

I wouldnt really mind that much cause i simple task kill is all it takes but what annoys me the most is that preferences are not saved. No studio.nfx file anywhere to be found and that means each time i start winamp i start with all my options gone (including hotkeys and everything).

Anything i can do to find the problem and fix it?

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling and re-installing Winamp yet?

Comment: Yes did it with revo uninstaller (not big difference, but tried to get rid of everything). Deleted winamp folder too.

Comment: As a test if you have the media library configured and populated with files from different locations, would you mind nuking it? (I believe you can use `Library / Export Media Database` first and `Library / Import Media Database` after testing without the library.)

Comment: I dont mind. but I guess reinstalling should have taken care of that no?. I will try it anyways.

Comment: Nothing new, any ideas guys?

Answer (score 0):

You could try getting a copy of Sysinternal's Process Monitor, and then monitor Winamp as you close it, and see the various things it is doing. Maybe it is crashing while writing a file. You would see the file open event and know that.  I've fixed buggy programs like this before.